# google API places ID cant find the id

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-places-api

I'm trying to get the place ID from a business on google.

I've searched it in this widget but it does not show
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id

I followed this site
https://www.launch2success.com/guide/find-any-google-id/

and I get returned this from my request,  any ideas?

```
{
"error_message": "The provided Place ID is no longer valid. Please refresh cached Place IDs as per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id#save-id",
"html_attributions": [],
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
```